# About .p12 certificate and how to extract keys from it

Tags: certificate, x509certificate

What is the difference between a certificate in a .cer file and one in a .p12 file? Are they just in different formats?

How do I extract the private key and public key from the .p12 file? Can this be done using Java keytool?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can export from PKCS12 to JKS uisng Java Keytool. 
https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/626.html
If you want something else. I can provide Java code for getting the certifcate and private key from PKCS12.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I tried using keytool from your suggested web site. It works. Thanks. Could you post this as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I posted my opinion as answer as you have told. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export from PKCS12 to JKS using Java Keytool. 

Please check this link:  https://www.tbs-certificates.co.uk/FAQ/en/626.html. 
If you want something else. I can provide Java code for getting the certifcate and private key from PKCS12.